# tflite models from tfhub.dev not working in Android

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am trying to use custom model detection using TensorFlow in android and I am using pre-train models from the official TensorFlow site. 3 out of 4 models are not working getting this error in the log.

```html
E/CameraXDetectionActivit: onFailure: 
    com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Failed to initialize detector. Unexpected number of dimensions for output index 0: got 3D, expected either 2D (BxN with B=1) or 4D (BxHxWxN with B=1, W=1, H=1).
        at com.google.mlkit.vision.vkp.PipelineManager.start(com.google.mlkit:vision-internal-vkp@@18.0.0:63)
        at com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.custom.internal.zzg.tryLoad(com.google.mlkit:object-detection-custom@@16.3.1:3)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.model.CustomModelLoader.load(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.1:3)
        at com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.custom.internal.zzh.load(com.google.mlkit:object-detection-custom@@16.3.1:2)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.ModelResource.zza(Unknown Source:18)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzn.run(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzp.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.1:2)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zze(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.1:4)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzc(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzj.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzd(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzk.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

models which I have tried is:

[aiy/vision/classifier/birds_V1](https://tfhub.dev/google/aiy/vision/classifier/birds_V1/1) (working)

[efficientdet/lite0/detection](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientdet/lite0/detection/1) (not working)

[ssd_mobilenet_v1](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/ssd_mobilenet_v1/1/default/1) (not working)

[Mobile object_localizer_v1.1](https://tfhub.dev/google/object_detection/mobile_object_localizer_v1/1) (not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're using ML Kit's object detection API with [custom model](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models#use_a_pre-trained_image_classification_model). It first identifies objects in the image, and run **image classification** on those objects to determine what the object is. Hence, the model's output is class probability.

On the other hand, other models are actual **object detection** models, and outputs four tensors representing bounding box positions and classes.

Please refer to following example for using those detection models.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview